# Inner section in Elementor issue for phone screen

Tags: elementor

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5xxh.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWJnx.jpg)

Hello, I have an issue. I did add 2 inner sections in Elementor which contain 3 columns. For desktop, it looks great but for the phone, I cannot make it into 2 columns. Anybody can advise me, please?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have a hard time doing this if your content is split between different inner sections.

Here's how you could do it with a little CSS.

(1) Create a new section with just one column, and add all your content to this one column. For illustration, I'm using paragraphs but the same principle will apply for other content.
[image]

(2)Go to section settings > advanced > advanced, and give this section a class of 'item-wrap'
[image]

(3) Go to section settings > advanced > custom CSS and add the following

```
/* set default widget width to 50% */
.item-wrap .elementor-widget-wrap>.elementor-element {
    width: 50%;
}


/* set widget width to 33.33% on tablet and desktop */
@media(min-width:768px){
    .item-wrap .elementor-widget-wrap>.elementor-element {
       width: 33.33%;
    }
}
```

(4) Here's the end result. Depending on the specifics of your page, we may need to tweak the CSS selectors in step 3. Give this a try and let me know how it goes.

[image]

[image]